# What is the concept of God according to Nyaya school of thought in Hinduism?

Tags: schools

Nyaya school of thought is a theistic School of Thought within Hinduism.

They believe that God revealed the Vedas.

So what is the concept of God according to Nyaya ? And how it is different from the Vedanta schools?

Comment: these are very broad questions.. it's like trying to get a degree with 1-by-1 questions, there are entire curriculum devoted for this in Veda Patashalas and Sanskrit colleges

Comment: See Prof Sharma's chapter on the Nyaya school here - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

God is the a source of right knowledge.

Nyaya Sutra (ii. 68),

> the fact of the Veda's being a cause of right knowledge, like spells
> and the medical science, follows from the fact that the fit one who
> gave the Veda was a source of right knowledge.

Udayana in the fourth chapter of the Kusumaanjali chapter 4

> He in whose intuitive unerring perception, inseparably united to Him
> and dependent on no foreign inlets, the succession of all the various
> existing objects is contained,— He, Śiva, is my authority; what have I
> to do with others, darkened as their authority must ever be with
> rising doubts?"

Íśvara is a cause of right knowledge (pramánạ) because he is pramáyá áśrayah, according to Nyaya sutras

Book 4, Chapter 1 of the Nyaya Sutras examines in detail the creation and destruction of life/matter and attributes it to Ishvara (4.1.19 etc.)

Comment: And how it is different from Vedanta schools

Comment: @Dark Knight Vedanta does not accept God as the author of the Vedas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Dark Knight Thanks for accepting my answer. Kindly note that mimansa argues vehemently against this concept of God being the author of vedas.

Comment: your welcome. But mimamsa doesn't believe in God in first place.

Comment: @Dark Knight Yes, indeed. The view that vedas are authorless and not from God is from mimansa and then adapted by Vedanta. The primary arguments that the vedas are authorless and not by God is all done by mimansa.

Comment: Nice answer sir!